# Latency and Security in using Apigee Cloud

Tags: security, latency, apigee

I am new to Apigee, and just started using Apigee Edge cloud solution. I need to know some answers. It will be very helpful for me.

1. What is the latency in using the Apigee cloud instead of On premise solution. I would also like to know what is the downtime percentage as if I am using Apigee server I am completely dependent on them.
2. Apigee provided me with an organiztion account which is having a username and password, is there any other authtication though which apigee recognizes that the request is coming from my account ony, and the same goes for the response, I am asking these as anybody can hack my URL and send the same request.
3. As our API's will be containing the data for financial transaction, I am a bit worried about the keeping my data on the cloud and passing through Apigee server. What kind of security is there on the cloud?

Thanks in advance , Kindly dont mind if my quesitions are very basic.

Comment: These questions are more suited for Apigee support channels.

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting from [Apigee Community](https://community.apigee.com/questions/9074/latency-and-security-in-using-apigee-cloud.html),

- Latency depends on several things, region, complexity, load and many more, its applicable for both on-prem and cloud. We have seen several Apigee customers both in cloud and on-prem having a apigee added latency of just few milliseconds to few hundred milliseconds. Its hard to tell a number, but the good news is Apigee provides tools to understand your latency across all the dimensions. Its minimal latency.
- Regarding availability, Apigee cloud offers upto 99.99% availability, you could also check status.apigee.com for more details.
- There is variety of options to secure your API, oauth, saml, IPs, Keys, basic authentications, open id etc.. Please find more about security related policy [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/reference-overview-policy).
- Cloud has PCI, and we also have some financial services customers in the cloud. Please find more information [here](http://www.slideshare.net/apigee/does-your-api-need-to-be-pci-compliant).